# How to improve the performance of a stock data transfer application?

Tags: java, performance

This is a question which I have worked for several years, but now I still don't get a good solution.

My application has two part:

1. The first one is running in a server which is called "ROOT server". It will receive the realtime stock data from HKEx(Securities and futures exchange in Hong Kong), and broadcast them to 5 other children servers. It will append a timestamp to each data item when broadcasting.
2. The second ones are running in the "children" servers. They will receive the stock data from ROOT server, parse each of them, and get the important information. At last, they will send them in a new text format to the clients. The clients may be hundreds to thousands, they can register for some kind of stocks, and get the realtime information of them.

The performance is the most important thing. In the past several years, I tried all kinds of solutions I know to make it faster. The "faster" here means, the first one will receive and send the data to the children servers as fast as it can, and the children servers will receive and parse and send the data to the clients as fast as they can.

For now, when the data speed is 200K from HKEx and there are 5 children servers, the first one application will have 10ms latency for each data item in average. And the second one is not easy to test, it depends on the clients count.

What I'm using:

1. OpenSUSE 10
2. Sun Java 5.0
3. Mina 2.0

The server hardware:

1. 4-core CPU (I don't know the type)
2. 4G ram

I'm considering how to improve the performance.

1. Do I need to use a concurrent framework as [akka](http://akka.io)
2. try another language, e.g. Scala? C++?
3. use the [real-time java system](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/realtime/index.jsp)?
4. your advices...

Need your help!

---

Update:

The applications have logged some important information for analysis, but I don't find any bottlenecks. The HKEx will provide more data in the next year, I don't think my application will be fast enough.

One of my customer have tested our application and another company's, but ours didn't have advantage in speed. I just want to find a way to make it faster.

**How is the first application running**

The first application will receive the stock data from HKEx and broadcast them to several other servers. The steps are:

1. It connects HKEx
2. logins
3. reads the data. The data is in binary format, each item has a head, which is 2 bytes of integer which means the length of body, then body, then next item.
4. put them into a hashmap in memory. Key is the sequence of the item, value is the byte array.
5. log the sequence of each received item into disk. Use log4j's buffer appender.
6. a daemon thread try to read the data from hashmap, and inserts them into postgresql in every 1 minute. (this is just used to backup the data)
7. when clients connect to this server, it accepts them and try to send all the data from hashmap from memory. I used thread pool in mina, the acceptor and senders are in different threads.

I think the logic is very simple. When there are 5 clients, I monitored the speed of transfer is only 1.5M/s at most. I used java to write a simplest socket program, and found it can be 10M/s.

Actually, I've spent more than 1 year trying all kinds of solutions on this application, just to make it faster. That why I feel desperate. Do I need to try another language than Java?

---

**about 10ms latency**

When the application received a data from HKEx, I will record the timestamp for it. When the root server broadcast the data to the children servers, it will append the timestamp to the data.

when children server get the data, it will send a message to root server to get the current timestamp, then compare them.

So, the 10ms latency contains:

1. root server got the data  ---> the child server got the data
2. child server send a request for root server's timestamp ---> root server got it

But the 2nd one is very small that we can ignore it.

Comment: Where's your bottleneck? If you don't find that out you're just throwing optimisations at a wall and seeing what sticks.

Comment: The most obvious thing to try if to upgrade Java.  This may work without having to change code. A 10 ms latency is enormous. We have two data centres more than 20 km apart and they have a 0.3 ms latency. How far apart are the senders and receivers? I would expect a typical latency for a Java application over a 1 Gb network is around 0.2 ms. With a custom solution you can cut this to less than 0.1 ms. On the same box (over loopback) I would expect between 10 and 50 micro-seconds latency (in Java)

Comment: I think it's inet channel problem firstly, secondly - you need to provide some info about your data manipulations to understand what and where can be also improved

Comment: I don't find any bottleneck. But our customer has tested the speed: He used our product and another company's to get the same stock, but our data is later than others about 0.5 second.

Comment: It could be that you are getting the data later. There delay could be external to your system. However I would try to get your end-to-end latency well below 1 ms.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I can't believe that the latency of your application is so small! Let me update the question to tell you more about my application.

Comment: have you played with Mina's tuning?http://mina.apache.org/configuring-thread-model.html Have tried looking at JConsole charts if there isn't some garbage collector issue? Have you tried some Sun JVM tuning?

Comment: @MarianP, Yes, I've spent a lot of time configuring mina. I've following that article to setting my application.

Comment: @MarianP, And I have used JProfiler to monitor the application. And found some important methods used the most execution time, and this is correct.

Comment: have you tried to turn off the logging?

Comment: how does garbage collection process look like?

Comment: @MarianP, I've tried turned off the logging. The result is nearly the same. The gc thread looks normal.

Comment: does the problem scale up when adding client servers?

Comment: I can't understand why we are discussing about low latency when you client refreshes data once a minute... I have done something similar, with real-time updates, ComteD push, and my prices are arriving earlier than the prices coming from other brokers...I am available to discuss about it privately

Comment: For your own interest, try http://speedtest.net/ and see what the ping latency is.  I suspect is lower than 10 ms, but if its not, you may have a problem with your network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have checked everything, and found no obvious performance optimizations, you may need to change the architecture to get better performance. This would obviously be most fruitful if you could at least identify where your application is spending time - sounds like there are several major components:

- The HK Ex server (out of your control)
- The network between the Exchange and your system
- The "root" server
- The network between the "root" and the "child" servers
- The "child" servers
- The network between "child" servers and the client
- The clients

To know where to spend your time, money and energy, I'd at least want to see an analysis of those components, how long each component takes (min, max, avg), and what the specification is of each resource.

Easiest thing to change is hardware - bigger servers, more memory etc., or better bandwidth. Can you see if any of those resources are constrained?

Next thing to look at is to change the communication protocol to be more efficient - how do clients receive the stocks? Can you reduce data size? 1.5M for only 5 clients sounds a lot...

Next, you might look at some kind of quality of service solution - provide dedicated hardware for "premium" customers, with reduced resource contention, more servers, more bandwidth - this will probably require changes to the architecture.

Next, you could consider changing the architecture - right now, your clients "pull" data from the client servers. You could, instead, "push" data out - that way, you shave off the polling interval on the client end.

At the very end of the list, I'd consider a different technology stack; Java is a fine programming language, but if absolute performance is a key priority, C/C++ is still faster. Clearly, that's a huge change, and a well-written Java app will be faster than a poorly written C/C++ app (and far more stable).

Comment: thanks for you nice advices. The architecture is very important, now I'm thinking using [memcachedb](http://memcachedb.org/) to replace part of current application. I think it will be faster to transfer data from root to children servers.

Comment: Memcached is a great way to cache common data - but I don't think that's your problem right now. In fact it may make things slower - because it presupposes that the root server will push data to the cache, and that the children will poll that cache - the polling takes time, and when 50ms is the difference between success and failure, you can't afford that time.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to do to find performance bottlenecks is to find out where most of the time is spent. A way to determine this is to use a profiler.

There are open source profilers available such as http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/, or commercial profilers such as Yourkit Java Profiler.

One easy thing to do could be to upgrade the JVM to Java SE6 or Java 7. General JVM performance improved a lot at version 6. See the [Java SE 6 Performance White Paper](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/6performance.html) for more details.

Comment: I have tried JProfiler to profile the application, but don't find anything strange. I will try Java 7 in the future, I think it's not stable enough for now.

Comment: @Freewind, Java 6 update 27 is stable and gets almost the same performance as Java 7. Java 6 is likely to be less buggy the the relatively unsupported Java 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

To trace the source of the delay I would add timing data to your end to end process.  You can do this using an external log, or by adding meta data to your messages.

What you want to get is a timestamp at key stages in your application 3-5 is enough to start with.  Normally I would use System.nanoTime() because I am looking for micro-second delays, but in your case System.currentTimeMillis() is likely to be enough, esp if you average over many samples (you will still get 0.1 ms accuracy on an average, with Ubuntu)

Compare time stamps for the same messages as it passes through your system and look for the highest average delay.  Once you have found this try breaking this interval into more stages to zoom in on the problem.

I would analyse any stage which has a verage delay over over 1 ms for your situation.

If clients are updating every minute, there might not be a good technical reason to do this, but you don't want to be seen as being slow and your traders at a disavantage even if in reality it won't make a difference.

Comment: @PeterLayrey, sorry for the unclear expression in my question, the server will send data to client in realtime. "every minute", is just the interval of a thread which saves the data into postgresql for backing up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm thinking about this problem now and trying to find the reason again.